# Can the SharePoint 2007 site's MasterPage opened?

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages

There was a Sharepoint 2007 site that was maintained without touching the code. People had their masterpage set by using links in the UI, SiteActions>>(under Look & Feel)MasterPage selecting default.master.

Now, they need some changes in the masterpage.

When I opened the site in Sharepoint designer 2007, the masterpage was referenced as MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master".

I want to open this master page which they refer to ~masterurl/default.master.

I have checked every .master inside the _catalogs folder but nothing is fruitful.

My task is to identify the masterpage they have used & to modify it.

Help me loacte the master page ~masterurl/default.master

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the master pages in the Master Page Gallery? Go to Site Settings -> [Galleries] Master pages.

Comment: The context menu on the gallery items has an 'Edit in Microsoft Office Sharepoint Designer' option.

Answer (score 0):

`MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"` is a dynamic token and it set to "`/_catalogs/masterpage/default.master`" by default.

Check msdn for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476046(office.12).aspx

Comment: But, if I reference the _catalogs>>masterpage>>default.master replacing ~masterurl/default.master in the particular .aspx page via designer, the LeftNavigation pane disappears..(as I was one who disabled it somedays before)..

And hence i guess, this default.master is not referred.

Can you please suggest me?

Comment: Check this link, I suspect Installed default master page as 'Default' had been changed. [Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/change-the-current-master-page-HA010167165.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can open the master page from the master page gallery. But don't just edit it, save it with a new name and edit it afterwards. You can assign the master page to your pages later.

see:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-or-edit-a-master-page-HA010157775.aspx